# What to do when npm install fails to find one dependency, but you can download it normally?

Tags: javascript, npm

So I am trying to run a javascript file that comes with a package.json file. When I run npm install in the folder, it fails because it doesn't find one of the dependencies.

I can then remove this dependency from the package.json file, and download it manually from the location provided and put it in a different folder. The npm install will then complete.

I can also run "npm install" on the downloaded dependency folders to have all of its dependencies.

Problem is, now I end up with 2 folders, with many different scripts in each folder, and two package.json files.

What is the proper way to handle this scenario?

Can I somehow point the original package.json my local hardrive, or where I found the file on the internet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the npm link command, it allows you to locally symlink a package to another folder.

Remove the manually downloaded dependency from the top-level package.json file.
Run npm install in the top-level directory to install the remaining dependencies.
Navigate to the folder containing the manually downloaded dependency.
Run npm link in that folder. This will create a global symlink for the package.
Navigate back to the top-level directory and run npm link .
This will create a symlink in the node_modules folder of the top-level directory, pointing to the manually downloaded dependency.
By using npm link, you can avoid duplicating the dependency and manage it as a symlink.